# Top border wont show up

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-gui

My top border wont show up, its getting put behind the other layout, how can I make it come up?

this is the image of what i need since i cant post images yet  http://tinypic.com/r/33nhk4k/5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/AliceBlue" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/Blue"
    android:gravity="top" >

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/AliceBlue" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/Blue"
    android:gravity="top" >

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Setup width and height of LinearLayout or add some views to it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the blue border is added first in the RelativeLayout, whatever is added first gets rendered on top.

[Z-index in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299944/z-index-in-android)

Comment: so how do i do that? did u see the picture?

Answer (score 0):

You give the gravity top to the linearlayout. So it come above of relative layout. Use android:id for both layouts . And second layout must be below first layout. So use below property of layout.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the `LinearLayout` because it has width and height set to `wrap_content` and there is no content.

Answer (score 0):

brillenheini has the answer. If you want to see the border, give it some height (e.g 20dp) cause wrap content without a content won't have any height.